# User Profile Sync status stuck at “Synchronizing” every time it runs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, profile-sync

We have SharePoint 2013 and every time it runs, that status remains on **Synchronizing** although it is importing user profiles. In order to make it idle we do the following:

1. Click on **Stop** in Central Administration the screen will show **stopping** for the **Profile Synchronization Status**

[image]

2. Reboot the server than runs User Profile Service (We tried to restart both FIM services from services.msc console, but that did not work)

This happens every day. I am not sure why this is happening and how to fix it. I did look at this article, but that did not help:

[User Profile Sync status stuck at "Synchronizing"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57656/user-profile-sync-status-stuck-at-synchronizing)

Any idea how to troubleshoot/fix the issue?

Comment: Try checking timer job status. Most of the times the errors lead somewhere.

Comment: i would check the ULS logs and Event Log at the same time when Sync started....from Event Log also check the System log too.

Comment: In addition to what @WaqasSarwarMCSE already mentioned also check the Synchronization Service Manager for any possible error. Usually found at the below path. What is the source that you are importing from?     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe

Comment: No errors in miisclient.exe.

Comment: Are you seeing "Runs" in the MIIS Client? It should be logging the runs and a run should be named after your connection.